# Triggered Sends, Speed Up Delivery Time

Tags: marketing-cloud

Whenever we use a Triggered Send to send an email, it can sit in the queue up to 5 minutes. Is there a way to expedite the sending of these emails? We are sending opt-in and password reset emails and it would be nice if they can be sent immediately.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Priority to High?

Comment: Thanks @victorcorey,  I'm trying it and it looks like it is helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Victor mentioned, the solution is to set the priority to 'high' in the Triggered Email. If this option is not available on your account (it may not be) then you will need to request it to be enabled.

> **Caution:** messages sent with a high priority [count as four Super Messages](http://www2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/marketing_cloud_super_message_bundles.pdf) — yes that's right, they cost four times as much a regular triggered Email!

### Update

If you are using the new [transactional messaging API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm) from the January 2019 release, all messages are counted as one super message and are sent "as fast as possible".

Comment: Thanks Eliot.  I don't see any documentation supporting that a high priority triggered send cost 4 times as a regular email.  Where did you find this?

Comment: Refer to the link in my Answer http://www2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/marketing_cloud_super_message_bundles.pdf

Comment: I was looking for documentation on Salesforce's site about this but couldn't find anything.  I'll contact them.

Comment: I checked with the SFMC product manager who is responsible for this area who explained that high priority emails take priority over other activities (SMS, automations, etc) and they need to use additional infrastructure resources to ensure these high priority emails 'jump the queue', hence the additional cost.